# C++ - error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token

Tags: c++, mysql-connector

I'm having trouble compiling this class. I'm trying to inherit the `StoreQueryResult` object which holds the results/rows from a MySQL query in order to apply some custom exception handling mechanism for array subscript operator

Here is the code

```
/* MySQLQueryResult.h */


#ifndef MYSQLQUERYRESULT_H
#define MYSQLQUERYRESULT_H

#include <mysql++.h>
#include <result.h>

namespace  MinesScanner {

    namespace MoonStone {

        class MySQLQueryResult : protected StoreQueryResult {
        public:

            MySQLQueryResult();


            MySQLQueryResult(const MySQLQueryResult &other);

            MySQLQueryResult& operator=(const MySQLQueryResult &other);

            MySQLQueryResult& operator[](int index);

        private:

            double empty_val = 0.0;



        };

    }

}

#endif  /* MYSQLQUERYRESULT_H */
```

and the corresponding source file

```
/* MySQLQueryResult.cpp */

#include "MySQLQueryResult.h"

namespace MinesScanner {

    namespace MoonStone {

        MySQLQueryResult::MySQLQueryResult( )
        {
            StoreQueryResult( ) ;
        }

        MySQLQueryResult::MySQLQueryResult( const MySQLQueryResult &ob )
        {
            StoreQueryResult( const StoreQueryResult & ob ) ;
        }

        MySQLQueryResult& MySQLQueryResult::operator=( const StoreQueryResult &ob )
        {

            StoreQueryResult::operator=( ob ) ;
            return *this ;

        }

        MySQLQueryResult& MySQLQueryResult::operator[]( int index )
        {

            try {

                Row *val = ( *this ).at( index ) ;
                return *val ;
            } catch ( std::out_of_range& excpn_ob ) {
                return *empty_val ;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

gcc reports this error when compiling

```
./MySQLQueryResult.h:20:61: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
./MySQLQueryResult.cpp: In constructor ‘MinesScanner::MoonStone::MySQLQueryResult::MySQLQueryResult()’:
./MySQLQueryResult.cpp:16:22: error: ‘StoreQueryResult’ was not declared in this scope
```

And here are the lines from the make file

```
CXX := g++ 
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -g -std=c++11 -I/usr/bin/include/mysql++ -I/usr/include/mysql  
LDFLAGS := -L/usr/lib64 -lmysqlpp -lnsl -lz -lm -L/usr/lib64/mysql  -lmysqlclient -lboost_date_time
EXECUTABLE := main

mysqlqueryresult.o : ./Moon_Stone_Scanner/MySQLQueryResult.cpp
    ${CXX} -c ${CXXFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} ./Moon_Stone_Scanner/MySQLQueryResult.cpp

main.o:  main.cpp
    ${CXX} -c ${CXXFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} mysqlqueryresult.o main.cpp
```

So as far i can see `mysql++.h` is being included before the lines in which the error occurs and is also included during compilation but still i'm getting that error which says `error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token` . Please let me know where i went wrong .

Comment: What is in `result.h`? Is there a class definition that is terminated with a semi-colon? Also: is it a system include? Otherwise use `#include "result.h"`. And: What is `protected` inheritance supposed to accomplish? Isn't it better to use `private` inheritance?

Comment: It's also telling you that it doesn't know `StoreQueryResult`, which it should at that point. Are you missing an include for it? Perhaps a namespace specifier, like `mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult`?

Comment: result.h contains the mysql connector classes. Its a system include. mysql++.h includes all these sub classes.

Comment: http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/refman/result_8h-source.html here is the source of this file

Comment: @Maxx As you can see from the source you've linked, it is within the `mysqlpp` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a few things then.

- The `StoreQueryResult` resides in the `mysqlpp` namespace. This means that you need to add this namespace specifier (either through `using namespace mysqlpp` or prepending with `mysqlpp::`). The former should only be done in your `.cpp` file. So, change your `protected StoreQueryResult` to `protected mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult`
- In the cpp-file, add: `using namespace mysqlpp;` (just after your include directives in the top). This solves most of your issues.
- When calling the base constructor, instead of:

  ```
  MySQLQueryResult::MySQLQueryResult( )
  {
      StoreQueryResult( ) ;
  }

  MySQLQueryResult::MySQLQueryResult( const MySQLQueryResult &ob )
  {
      StoreQueryResult( const StoreQueryResult & ob ) ;
  }
  ```

  Do:

  ```
  MySQLQueryResult::MySQLQueryResult( )
    : StoreQueryResult()
  {
  }

  MySQLQueryResult::MySQLQueryResult( const MySQLQueryResult &ob )
    : StoreQueryResult( ob )
  {
  }
  ```
- Your `MySQLQueryResult& MySQLQueryResult::operator=( const StoreQueryResult &ob )` is missing in the header file. Add this:

  ```
  MySQLQueryResult& operator=(const mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult &ob);
  ```
- Your `[]` operator seems pretty fishy to me. `empty_val` isn't defined anywhere I know of.

---

Probably not relevant to your setup but I also had to add `-I/usr/include/mysql++` to the makefile.

Comment: Yes that worked flawlessly. And thanks a lot for the above advice, i have refactored the code according to your advice. The variable empty_val is to send error codes in.

Comment: Hi I wanted to ask one more question. In the child class `MySQLQueryResult` how do i refer to the data member. So in `MySQLQueryResult& operator=(const mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult &ob)` how do i refer to the current object. Eg in a assignment like this `MySQLQueryResult res = getVal()` how do i  refer to the ob `res` within the `operator=` function

Comment: Typically `stackoverflow` is meant to be on the Q/A format, and relevant for people in similar situation. If you have more questions, you should create a new question explaining the situation, and let people help you there. You are probably thinking about the "assignment operator". Look that up ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change `StoreQueryResult` into `mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult`. It is in the `mysqlpp` namespace.